# Displaying only selected values from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php   

$sql = "SELECT * FROM team;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql );

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$teamname = $row[1];

echo $teamname;
```

Consider table in DB consists of 10 names from 1-10. That will be displayed on the screen as usually (using retrieving), but the problem is when I click any name from 1-10 displaying on the screen that should open a new page by displaying only the particular name I selected.

I tried this but, all the values are displaying.

Comment: If you expect more than one row, you need to loop over `mysqli_fetch_rows()`.

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: @Arjun if you click on your name then you need to send you `id` to tell DB to get only your name, here in your query there is nothing like `where id = yourID`

Comment: "detail" pages generally have a id  which is feeded into a url... `team.php?team_id=1` catch the team_id with `$_GET['team_id']` and use it in the query something like `SELECT * FROM team WHERE team.id = $_GET['team_id']`  but keep in mind the [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) **very important**

Comment: can we use * there in spite of giving condition @RaymondNijland ?

Answer (score 1):

First, add to your mysql table a column called "ID" to associate a number to each name.

After you can direct the user to your page like this

```
<a href="www.example.com/page.php?id=1">Name n.1</a> // etc..
```

so you can take the id of your name using GET and display to your page only that name

(Always use [Prepared Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) even when it is not strictly necessary)

**PHP script**

```
$name_id = $_GET['id'];

// connect to your db

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM team WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$name_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
 echo $result['name'];
```

if you need anything else, comment below.